# Set fallback directory with BABYLON.SceneLoader.AppendAsync and gltf file

Tags: babylonjs, gltf

I'm trying to modify an existent project, I would like to set a fallback texture when I load a GLTF file

```
BABYLON.GLTFFileLoader.IncrementalLoading = false;
        BABYLON.SceneLoader.AppendAsync(rootPath, 'data:' + gltfContent, scene, undefined, '.gltf').then(function () {
            scene.createDefaultCameraOrLight(true);
            scene.activeCamera.attachControl(canvas);
            scene.activeCamera.wheelDeltaPercentage = 0.005;
```

I don't know exactly how to do it.
what's the better way to proceed? should I read the GLTF and modify the URI?
I think it is a better solution to use some callback
Anyone is an expert with babylon.js?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babylon's GLTF 2.0 loader has an extension system that can be seen as promise-based plugin for each step of the loading process.
You can see a few examples for the extensions here:

https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/tree/master/loaders/src/glTF/2.0/Extensions

What can be very interesting in your case is here:

https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/blob/master/loaders/src/glTF/2.0/Extensions/KHR_texture_transform.ts

As you can see, this extension contains a function called `loadTextureInfoAsync` that returns a promise when done, after receiving the texture info that is about to be loaded.

Depending on your use case you can completely replace the load texture functionality or extend it (like in the example above). To override it you should just implement the function yourself:

```
public loadTextureInfoAsync(context: string, textureInfo: ITextureInfo, assign: (babylonTexture: BaseTexture) => void): Nullable<Promise<BaseTexture>> {
    const texture = loadTheTextureYourselfWithFallback();
    return Promise.resolve(texture);
}
```

Of course, the load function needs to be implemented according to your logic.